# MongoDB v3.4.5 bug?

Tags: mongodb, debugging

So I have a database demo and collection say test.

There are a total of **17** documents and one of them is marked as *deleted: true*

and the following is my query to get count of all documents:

```
db.test.find().count()
```

The above returns 11 (should have been 17)

When I try the below:

```
db.test.find({"deleted": {"$ne": true}).count()
```

It returns me 16

and when I try:

```
db.test.find({"deleted": true}).count()
```

It returns me 1

Is some setting causing this kind of behaviour or is this a bug in mongoDB v3.4.5?

EDIT: Tested the following in v3.4.9 and it works as expected so I am guessing this is a bug

Comment: you can check out the [changelogs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-changelog/#id84) for 3.4.6 through 3.4.9, but I didn't see anything that struck out to me as the cause

Comment: Apparently this issue is caused when you import data which can be corrupted. It seems to work on other collections. No other probable cause.

Comment: With WiredTiger a collection `count()` without any query criteria is a fast/estimated count which is persisted periodically. This count may be [inaccurate after unclean shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#accuracy-after-unexpected-shutdown), but can be corrected by running `validate` on the affected collection. I suspect this is the problem you encountered. The examples you have including query criteria will be accurate but somewhat slower (at scale) as they involve counting index keys or documents (if there are no suitable indexes).

Answer (score 0):

it is a bug planned to be solved in mongodb 3.7